# Tell me if this iphone app will work

Tags: iphone, safari

I'm looking at adding iphone support to an application in the simplest way possible. I don't have any experience writing code for the iphone, so I'm trying to keep it very simple. Here's my current concept of what the application will do:

1) Copy some data from the PC to the iphone - this would probably be sent by an application running on the PC, either over wireless or USB (whichever is easier)

2) Store the data locally on the iphone

3) View the data in Safari (or a web browser control in the application)

Originally I was hoping we could just let the user manually copy HTML files to the iphone to view, but apparently Safari on iphone doesn't let you view local files. :( Are there any other "gotchas" with the above ideas that I should be aware of (e.g. "you can't embed a web browser control in your application and have it view local files"), or should this concept work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one option: create an app that uses UIWebView. You can read data from files on the disk & also load other data over the net dynamically using javascript.

The advantage is you get the most up to date info via the net, with some navigation either in native app mode (more efficient) or using UIWebView.